# PHP Upload_max_filesize for different domains?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php7

I have various domains hosted on one server - however they all seem to load from the same PHP.ini.  I want the different domains to be able to upload different filesizes, for instance, our public facing website should have a very low filesize as users do not need to upload anything, so that would make the website secure if they filesize was small.

But for our staff-based websites, I need them to be able to upload large files (up to 100mb).  But I am reluctant to set the upload size so high as I feel it would compromise our public websites.

How can I set different upload sizes for the different domains?

Using Apache and Php 7.1

Answer (score 2):

Many  php.ini settings can also be placed inside the `<VirtualHost *:80>...</VirtualHost>` block when using mod_php with apache with the `php_admin_value` and `php_admin_flag` directives. See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 100M
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your server running with cPanel, you can install PHP.INI Manager plugin, you will get awesome features:

- List custom php.ini files, per user
- Ability to activate / deactivate the use of a custom php.ini file per-user
- Ability to update all custom php.ini files with the global copy
- Compatible with EasyApache4 and MultiPHP

Installation instructions:

- cd /usr/src
- wget https://download.how2.be/whm/phpinimgr/install_phpinimgr.sh
- chmod +x install_phpinimgr.sh
- sh install_phpinimgr.sh

The PHP.INI tabs will available on your WHM -> Plugins.